# How do I parse a default dict with values that are lists into independent dicts

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, mapping, defaultdict

**Trying to parse a defaultdict(list)**

**Input:**

```
defaultdict(class <'list'>,{'key1': ['v1', 'v2'], 'key2': [v3, v4], 'key3': ['v5', 'v6']})
```

**desired output:**

```
list_dic = [{key1: v1, key2: v3, key3: v5}, {key1: v2, key2: v4, key3: v6}]
```

**Has to work for n values in the lists.**

Following from the desired output, I intend to use mysql executemany to insert these values into a db. If anyone has any better suggestions of how I could insert a deafaultdict(list) into a table in mysql - I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post - ill get used to the etiquette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the answer lies in dic comprehension nested in list comprehension .
Please note that this piece of code relies on the input specificaly being a dictionnary with all the list being of the same length !

To test that , please run :

```
n = len(list(input.values())[0]
all_length_equal = all([len(v)==n for v in input.values()])
```

Once that is done, the code below goes through each value , picking up the i-value , and stores is into a dictionnary, try it with 0 :

```
{k:v[0] for k,v in input.items()}
```

Then you need to add a list comprehension

```
[ i for for i in range(len(list(input.values())[0])]
```

The above will return a range of number.
But if you combine the two, it will return the dictionnaries with i in range of the length of the first value.

```
list_dic = [{
     k:v[i] for k,v in input.items() #This create the correct dictionnary with all the i-values in the input
} for i in range(len(list(input.values())[0])] # iterate through the length of the first list
```

Comment: returns IndexError: list index out of range, could you please go in depth

Comment: That should mean that you have a list that is not the same length :/

Comment: I got it, my original dict has one value entry that was len 4 but the rest were len 2. 

So I ran del dict[key] as it's not necessary and then ran your code and it worked - thank you for your patience!